# How to sort by order with multiple columns alphabetically

Tags: sorting, sqlite, contacts

I have contacts database with
table having rows:

```
lastname text, firstname text, number text
```

I am querying to get the sorted result to display alphabetically, with "lastname" first sorting and "firstname" second sorting and then "number", and i want to list others which have NULL fields at last(below)

currently i am using

```
select * from table order by lastname IS NULL,firstname IS NULL ,number IS NULL
```

But not sorting properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by the columns as well, not only by "IS NULL"

```
select * from table
order by
    lastname IS NULL, lastname,
    firstname IS NULL, firstname,
    number IS NULL, number
```

Since SQLite uses `0` for `FALSE` and `1` for `TRUE` the null-entries should come last. See [Boolean Datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean)

Comment: Dude you saved my day! tonnes of thanks, wasted lot of time with the bug.